# $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{\mathbb{R}\setminus Q}\\ \sin x\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ is Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I would like to ask if this piecewise function $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{\mathbb{R}\setminus Q}\\ \sin x\text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ is Riemann Integrable?

I thought it was at first since both $x^3$ and $\sin x$ are Riemann integrable, because it had similarities to the modified Dirichlet's function, which is Riemann Integrable. But curiously the (unmodified) Dirichlet function is not Riemann Integrable. I was wondering why one is integrable but one is not, and if this can help me see if my function is integrable or not. Thanks.

Comment: Look at lower Riemann sums and upper Riemann sums over an interval $[a,b]$: can they ever converge?

Comment: As a spoiler for what is yet to come in your studies, although the function is not Reimann integrable, it *is* Lebesgue integrable (since $m(\mathbb{Q})=0$).

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(x)$ is bounded by one, when x is greater than one, the upper sum will take values corresponding to $x^3$, but the lower sum will take values of $\sin(x)$. And because a function is Riemann integrable if and only if the lower sum ($s(f)$) and the upper sum  (S(f)) satisfy  $|S(f)-s(f)|<\varepsilon$. this function won't be Riemann integrable

Answer (score 1):

Here is another explanation, that connects with some more sophisticated concepts.

A function is Riemann integrable iff it is *continuous almost everywhere*, with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Even if you haven't heard of Lebesgue measure, you can make sense of this statement!

Let's look at the points of continuity of $f(x)$. When $x^3\not=\sin x$, the function will have different limits as you approach $x$, depending on if you use rationals or irrationals. Thus the points of continuity of $f(x)$ are precisely the solutions of $x^3=\sin x$. There are only 3 solutions: $x\in \{0,\pm .929\}$. So for almost every value of $x$, the function is discontinuous at $x$.

Lebesgue measure makes the phrase "almost every" formal, because the measure of any finite set is 0. Thus the function is not Riemann integrable.

But as pointed out before, it *is* Lebesgue integrable, simply because it agrees almost everywhere with the nice function $x^3$.